# View or Sub-query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, view

**Users**(username,`Catogory_ID`,*`Sub_Catergory_ID`*)

**Categories** (`Catogory_ID`,Categories_Name)

**SubCatogoies**(`Sub_Catergory_ID`,SubCatogoies_Name)

In `code`  are FK's and its PK's

**Question 1**

What i required is to create a view using all these three tables **OR** a sub query to get the Catogory and Sub_Catogory names as its ID's

**Question 2**

In exec what will be more faster ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single query that pulls together data from all 3 tables would look something like this:

```
select u.*, c.Categories_Name, s.Sub_Categories_Name
    from Users as u
    left outer join Categories as c
        on c.Category_ID = u.Category_ID
    left outer join SubCategories as s
        on s.Sub_Category_ID = u.Sub_Category_ID;
```

This could be made into a view or simply run as is. As for performance, a materialized view might perform faster than the ad hoc query performing the joins upon each execution. But I wouldn't try to optimize along those lines unless you're seeing a performance problem. If the ad hoc query is fast enough, don't worry about optimizing it.